# iOS pushing view controller crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

### I am beginner to iOS development so I extend my due apologies if this question has already been asked. I request you to direct me to appropriate thread if this is the case.

I want to achieve a scenario where on clicking a label on a form on the first table view controller, another table view controller opens up which gives me a list of options which I can select for that label. Example: If the label is "Gender" on first table view controller, then clicking on an arrow next to it should open up another table view controller with rows as male, female.

The first controller is Edit Profile where I have the following code:

```
- (IBAction)btndrpSelect_Click:(id)sender {

DropDownViewController *secondView = [[DropDownViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DropDownViewController" bundle:nil];

self.GenderArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"Male", @"Female", nil];

secondView.drpOptions = self.GenderArray;

UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondView];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
```

}

The generic drop down table view controller has  the following code:

.h file:

```
@interface DropDownViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *drpOptions;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *drpOptions;

@end
```

.m file:

```
int count = [drpOptions count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
NSLog (@"Element %i = %@", i, [drpOptions objectAtIndex: i]);
```

---

When I click on the button on first view controller, I expect screen to flip and show me drop down options but it exits with error. Kindly guide.

Thanks

Comment: what error? please post that stack trace....

Comment: what's the error? You have to replace the default placeholder UITableView delegate/datasource implementations in the .m file, or it'll always crash.

Comment: Look at his code; he is trying to push a navigation controller onto a navigation controller. That will throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the stack trace and error code I can't answer your question for certain. However, by looking at your code I can see you try to push one navigation controller onto another. This will cause an error to be thrown. Delete this line of code:

```
UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondView];
```

and change your pushViewController code to this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

In your future programming endeavors, pay close attention to error codes; they can usually be quite helpful. Your error should have said something along the lines of "Pushing NavigationController not supported" which is very useful information and should be the first thing you Google.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to sort this